# How can I auto respond to a post in Facebook or Twitter from Social Studio Automate?

Tags: marketing-cloud, servicecloud, social-studio

We have created Data sources and Rules in Social Studio Automate so far and are able to successfully trace the posts in Twitter based on topic profiles (created in Social Studio. Also, we are able to create cases in Service Cloud based on questions being posted in Twitter. Apart from this, we also need to auto-respond to those posts with questions, so I want to know if that is possible through Social Studio Automate ?

Answer (score 1):

Social Studio does not offer built-in functionality that will allow for auto-replies. In large part, this is due to the Terms of Service of many Social Networks that will not allow "Bots", such as the auto-reply you are requesting.

That being said, this is still a good recommendation and perhaps there could be an opportunity to consider a version of this in a future release. You can search for existing ideas or log new ones using our IdeaExchange. For more information on using the IdeaExchange,

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch

For your reference, you can check the below articles,

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_sh_common_use_cases.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_sh_social_hub.htm&type=5

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't social Studio have an announced EOL?